# Installing OpenShift Origin on one node initially

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am evaluating openshift origin for our deployment and as i am starting my questions might be too basic or obvious but i couldnt find anything on google.

We want to install Origin on one server initially and after 3 to 4 months will add second server and after again 3 months will add third.

This is part of bigger deployment so we have to follow this way.

So can we do deployment in this way and deploying initially on one server would hamper any services??

Do i suppose to start with ALL in One Server as mentioned in below URL? and do it extendable as i require??

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html

**Edit1:**

Openshift 3.10 (OKD) on CentOS with glusterfs

I changed my inventory file like below

```
openshift_storage_glusterfs_is_native=false
openshift_storage_glusterfs_storageclass=true
openshift_storage_glusterfs_heketi_is_native=true
openshift_storage_glusterfs_heketi_executor=ssh
openshift_storage_glusterfs_heketi_ssh_port=22
openshift_storage_glusterfs_heketi_ssh_user=root
openshift_storage_glusterfs_heketi_ssh_sudo=false
openshift_storage_glusterfs_heketi_ssh_keyfile="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Following error while installing one node glusterfs. I have 80GB disk and before starting installation i run wipefs -a

```
TASK [openshift_storage_glusterfs : Create heketi DB volume] ************************************************************
fatal: [MY001.local]: FAILED! =>
{  
   "changed":true,
   "cmd":[  
      "oc",
      "--config=/tmp/openshift-glusterfs-ansible-PuHRNV/admin.kubeconfig",
      "rsh",
      "--namespace=glusterfs",
      "deploy-heketi-storage-1-dhbfv",
      "heketi-cli",
      "-s",
      "http://localhost:8080",
      "--user",
      "admin",
      "--secret",
      "BwyRN5bSXW+OnUe1ulU3rVtwt0ISOXRqamO1rw2VVms=",
      "setup-openshift-heketi-storage",
      "--image",
      "docker.io/heketi/heketi:latest",
      "--listfile",
      "/tmp/heketi-storage.json"
   ],
   "delta":"0:00:00.429962",
   "end":"2018-09-27 19:27:05.455025",
   "msg":"non-zero return code",
   "rc":255,
   "start":"2018-09-27 19:27:05.025063",
   "stderr":"Error: Failed to allocate new volume: No space\ncommand terminated with exit code 255",
   "stderr_lines":[  
      "Error: Failed to allocate new volume: No space",
      "command terminated with exit code 255"
   ],
   "stdout":"",
   "stdout_lines":[  

   ]
}
```

While searching i found that this issue is due to one node and this behaviour can be override with below command, But how we can override this in openshift ansible script?

```
heketi-cli volume create --durability=none --size=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start with `multiple masters`(3 masters) for suppressing potential influence of your service, OpenShift can not convert single master to multiple masters after installation [0].

But as your plan is possible, firstly `all-in-one` master deployment completed, then you can add your new node hosts [1].

- [0][https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install/example_inventories.html#multiple-masters]
- [1][https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#adding-cluster-hosts_manage-nodes]

Comment: I am able install it but glusterfs complain that i should have three servers. Any clue to install glusterfs on one and then extend later. We can directly install glusterfs on one server. Then how to make openshift to use that?

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan First you need to install a glusterfs with heketi, refer [this blog](https://keithtenzer.com/2017/03/24/storage-for-containers-using-gluster-part-ii/) for details. Then you define the storageclass for using glusterfs dynamically like [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/install_config/persistent_storage/dynamically_provisioning_pvs.html#glusterfs). I hope it help you. :)

Comment: thanks for pointing me to above links it look promising and i am getting error "Failed to allocate new volume: No space" details are provided in EDIT1